# Solving Dirichlet Problem for the Disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let
$$
\Delta u(r,\theta )=u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta }.
$$
Solve
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(r,\theta)=0&\text{ for }0<r<3, -\pi<\theta<\pi\\
u(3,\theta)=f(\theta)=\cos\dfrac{\theta}{2}&\text{ for }-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi
\end{cases}
$$
What I've tried:

We will take solutions given by $u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^n(A_n\cos n\theta +B_n\sin n\theta )$
And will use the boundary condition $f(\theta )=u(3,\theta )$.
Thus we have
$$
\begin{align}
A_n=\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(\theta )\cos(n\theta ) d\theta\\
B_n=\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(\theta )\cos(n\theta ) d\theta
\end{align}
$$
Can anybody help me figure this out? And am I on doing it correctly? Thanks a lot

Comment: There seems to be some information missing. You need boundary conditions on $r=0$, $r=3$, $\theta=-\pi$ and $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: So it should be $r^n$ not $3^n$ in the general expression for $u$ but in terms of computing the coefficients this looks right (besides the typo in $B_n$). Now can you compute the integrals?